# Is there a way to sort documents by an integer using faunaDB?

Tags: indexing, faunadb

Is there a way to sort documents by an integer with indexes using faunaDB? I have multiple documents with `data.likes`, which is an integer. Is it possible to simply get the documents by most likes sorted first, and the least sorted last? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

To do this, make sure that your index includes the `likes` field in the `values` definition. If you specify `reverse: true` for that field, you'll see the results sorted in descending order.

For example:

```
CreateIndex({
  name: 'popular-pets',
  source: Collection('pets'),
  values: [
    { field: ["data", "likes"], reverse: true },
    { field: ["ref"] },
  ],
})
```

Then you can do this:

```
Map(
  Paginate(Match(Index("popular-pets"))),
  Lambda(["likes", "ref"], Get(Var("ref")))
)
```